# apostrophe jungle

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, apostrophe

it is a very simple problem, but I get lost!

instead of this:

```
'select field1, f2, f3 from obs where id = 2800 order by obs.sort;'
```

I want this:

```
'select field1, f2, f3 from obs where id = ' $obsid ' order by obs.sort;'
```

where `$obsid` is a variable.

but I get lost in the apostrophe jungle when I try it.

I don't have much experience with sql and my native language is not english.
I'd really like to find a place where I can learn about apostrophes in sql-code.

thank you.

regards from Niels

Comment: Not only will using parameterised queries *(or prepared statements)* make this less painful, it will protect you from SQL Injection attacks...  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: There shouldn't be any apostrophe jungle in this case, since you don't need quotes around a number. What you're missing are the `.` characters to concatenate strings. `= ' . $obsid . ' order by`

Comment: But you should use the parametrized query as in the answer.

Comment: I did it like Barmar first suggested.
will learn more about the sane way later.

I thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The sane way is:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('select field1, f2, f3 from obs where id = ? order by obs.sort');
$stmt->execute([$obsid]);
```

This example is for [PHP language and PDO library](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-1027). Whatever your tech stack is it should have a similar syntax.

Comment: Even saner is to use `:name` parameters instead of `?`

Comment: @Barmar I agree. But when I use them as example I always get the opposite opinion :)